# What permissions would I need to give a developer for a Wordpress website?

Tags: linux, wordpress, reporting, administrative-privileges

I am hiring a web developer to create a theme and administer my plugins. I need new plugins but I also need them to run reports from my plugins.

I'm new to this so I want to know what permissions they would need to build the theme, fix problems with my website, administer plugins, and run reports from different plugins.

Should they have server access, WordPress admin privileges or both? I use A2hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to give them the administrator role, as that is the only role out of the box that can do anything to plugins.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#administrator

You could create a new role, but that would be more hassle than it is worth. If they are contributing code, then they could do anything via that code.

They may not need server access if they do it via the Wordpress web interface.